# Finding the next datetime based on a weekly, monthly schedule

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0

I am trying to find the next scheduled date based on either a monthly or a weekly schedule.

e.g.

```
ScheduleMode: M or W for monthly or weekly
Monthly:
    1|15|29 will run on the 1st, 15th and 29th of every month

Weekly:
    1|3|5 will run every Monday, Wednesday and Friday
```

how do I go about figuring out what the next Datetime will be based on this data?

e.g. 12/16/2013 running weekly 1|3|5, next schedule will be 12/18/2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try to use the Enum `System.DayOfWeek`. That happens to be the return type from `DateTime.DayOfWeek`, which you can use to find the weekday of the your starting date.

From that, you should be able to find the next day(s) using `DateTime.AddDays(x)` or `DateTime.AddMonths(X)` (with some simple addition and subtraction to take the current weekday or date into account when finding `x`).

Tip: If you have problems solving this, make sure you understand exactly what you *need* first. If necessary, write down your requirements in plain English before you try to code it. Once you've *defined the problem* clearly, solving it should actually not be too hard...

Answer (score 2):

I would use create a custom class `Schedule` to encapsulate the calculation and the data. Then you could fill a `List<Schedule>` (or a different collection-type/database) which you use as datasource.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public enum Type
    { 
        Monthly,
        Weekly
    }
    public Schedule(DayOfWeek weekDay)
    {
        this.ScheduleType = Type.Weekly;
        this.WeekDay = weekDay;
    }
    public Schedule(int monthDay)
    {
        if (monthDay < 1 || monthDay > 31)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid day");
        this.ScheduleType = Type.Monthly;
        this.MonthDay = monthDay;
    }
    public Type ScheduleType { get; set; }
    public int MonthDay { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek WeekDay { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the list and the initialization with your sample data:

```
private List<Schedule> _AllSchedules;
public List<Schedule> AllSchedules 
{
    get 
    {
        if (_AllSchedules == null)
        {
            _AllSchedules = new List<Schedule>();
            Schedule s1 = new Schedule(1);
            Schedule s2 = new Schedule(15);
            Schedule s3 = new Schedule(29);
            Schedule s4 = new Schedule(DayOfWeek.Monday);
            Schedule s5 = new Schedule(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
            Schedule s6 = new Schedule(DayOfWeek.Friday);
            _AllSchedules.AddRange(new[] { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 });
        }
        return _AllSchedules;
    }
}
```

Here's a possible (not thoroughly tested) implementation for the calculation which should give you an idea:

```
public DateTime? GetNextScheduledDate(DateTime from)
{
    var nextMonthDay = AllSchedules
        .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == Schedule.Type.Monthly && s.MonthDay >= from.Day)
        .OrderBy(s => s.MonthDay)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(AllSchedules
            .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == Schedule.Type.Monthly && s.MonthDay < from.Day)
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.MonthDay)
            .FirstOrDefault())
        .FirstOrDefault();
    var nextWeekDay = AllSchedules
        .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == Schedule.Type.Weekly)
        .Select(s => new { Schedule = s, Diff = ((int)s.WeekDay- (int)from.DayOfWeek) })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Diff >= 0)
        .ThenBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Diff))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    DateTime? nextMonthDate = null;
    DateTime? nextWeekDate = null;
    if (nextMonthDay != null)
    {
        int diff = nextMonthDay.MonthDay - from.Day;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            // next month
            nextMonthDate = from.AddMonths(1).AddDays(diff);
        }
        else
        { 
            // this month
            nextMonthDate = from.AddDays(diff);
        }
    }
    if (nextWeekDay != null)
    {
        nextWeekDate = from.AddDays(nextWeekDay.Diff < 0 ? 7 - Math.Abs(nextWeekDay.Diff) : nextWeekDay.Diff);
    }
    if (!nextMonthDate.HasValue && !nextWeekDate.HasValue)
        return null;
    else
        return nextMonthDate < nextWeekDate ? nextMonthDate : nextWeekDate;
}
```

Now it's simple and readable:

```
DateTime? nextScheduled = GetNextScheduledDate(DateTime.Today);
// nextScheduled.Value.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture): "12/16/2013"
```